# Why does fullcalendar events with ajax not work?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to use an ajax call in the events option of fullcalendar with a json feed, but it's not working. I am working in an asp.net mvc4 application. My ajax call works fine, returns json as expected, but as a test I am just trying to create a local array, called events, add some sample data and pass it to the callback. But for some reason this does not get set in the fullcalendar code, and this does not show on the rendered calendar. I am debugging into the fullcalendar source, but haven't yet figured out why it's not getting set. Any ideas?

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: false,
            timeFormat: '',
            height: 'auto',
            weekends: true,
            events: function (start, end, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/GetJson")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        start: start.toLocaleString("yyyy-mm-dd"),
                        end: end.toLocaleString("yyyy-mm-dd")
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, type, exception) { alert("Error: " + exception); },
                    success: function (response) {
                        var events = [];
                        events.push({
                            title: "new title",
                            start: "2014-11-05T13:15:30Z"
                        });
                        callback(events);
                    }
                    });  
            }
        });
```

I have confirmed fullcalendar works if I pass in a json string in the events option like this

```
events:
 [{ title: 'Event1', start: '2014-11-05T13:15:30Z' },
 { title: 'Event2', start: '2014-11-06T13:15:30Z' }]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using FullCalendar 2.*, the signature for [events as a function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) is:

```
function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { }
```

As long as your [event object is valid](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) (you need to have a `title` and a `start`), your code should work if you change

```
events: function (start, end, callback) {
```

to

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
```